# How to work with .mdf extension files using python?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a file with an extension .mdf in a path as below.

```
C:\A\B\sql\MP_000001.mdf;
```

I have installed pyodbc drivers as

[image]

To connect to the said database i have created a connection string as.

```
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'AttachDbFileName=C:\A\B\sql\MP_000001.mdf;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

It says an error as:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (123)')
```

How to specify connection parameters to open the .mdf file ?

Comment: Based on the mdf-extension, I suspect it is SQL Server database-file. You can not work with it as with ordinary file. You need to install MS SQL Server and attach this file to it

Comment: Simple: Using RESTORE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: `RESTORE` isn't relevant here, @BogdanSahlean ... Backup files, *normally* have the `.bak` extension; the OP has a database file that, along with the log file (and possibly other ndf files).

Comment: *If* the Op wanted to add the MDF file to an instance, they would [attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) it.